# Best features and tools over a short time interval

Tags: high-frequency, algorithmic-trading

For a short time interval, what are the features having the most impact on a stock price movement? In the same direction, what are the better tools to tell us the price movement tangent?

As tools, I thought ...

- Order flow imbalance
- Volume Imbalance
- Number of trades
- Number of limit and cancellation orders